# Windows Mobile GUI Options

Tags: c#, c++, user-interface, windows-mobile

I'm new to WinMo, and want to write a GUI application for a Windows Mobile Touch device.

I'm familiar with C#/C++, although not with any GUI development, and am writing a GUI for an application with a large C++ codebase which I've already ported to the platform successfully.

What would you reccomend for someone who is familiar with ObjectiveC/Cocoa to ease the transition to Windows GUI development?

Specifically:
1) What are the options? Langauages/Frameworks/Toolkits + Pro's/Con's.

2) What are the conventions? I guess I'm looking for something like the apple human interface guidelines for the iPhone.

3) Whats the best way to interface managed C# with unmanaged C++, pInvoke I assume?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've used the [WTL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wtl) to create applications for a Smart Phone, as you end up with a small EXE with few (if any) dependencies.  Worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 2, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158602.aspx

I've not done too much with different frameworks on WinMob, so I'm not in the best position to comment on the other questions...

Answer (score 0):

1) For GUI design you can choose between C++/MFC and the .NET Compact Framework. The recommended way of doing the UI (especially for a newcomer) is the .NET Compact Framework using C#. IDE support is great, the language and framework are very mature. It is almost like coding for a regular .NET platform.

Comment: I dont think you can use Managed C++ with the CF.

Comment: MFC is certainly not the only C++ option.  In fact I'd recommend to never use or even look at MFC.  WTL is a much better option.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do an enterprise application .NET is fine for you. But to do an application for the mass market with quick response I don't think .NET could do it.
I've seen some applications first done in .NET and then re-write in C++ because of performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

if your target windows mobile device has opengl support, have a look at [silvermoon](http://silvermoon.codeplex.com)